# Proof for logical implication : $\exists_x A(x) \rightarrow \forall_x B(x) \implies \forall_x [A(x) \rightarrow B(x)]$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

> Proof for logical implication : $\exists_x A(x) \rightarrow \forall_x B(x) \implies \forall_x [A(x) \rightarrow B(x)]$

Can you please see whether the proof is fine or not?

**We know that** $ {\forall_x B(x) \implies \exists_x B(x)} \\  [\exists_x A(x) \rightarrow \forall_x B(x)] \implies [\exists_x A(x) \rightarrow \exists_x B(x)] \implies \exists_x  \neg A(x) \lor \exists_x B(x) \implies \\\exists_x [A(x) \rightarrow B(x)]$

Please correct me if I am wrong. I have doubt in that bold alphabet step (can use or not, what happens when we have for all of $x$ in front of $A(x)$. I am doubtful if it is valid or not ... )

$\forall_x A(x) \rightarrow \forall_x B(x) \implies [\forall_x A(x) \rightarrow \exists_xA(x)\rightarrow \forall_x B(x)]  $

Can I say $\forall_x A(x) \rightarrow \forall_x B(x) \implies [ \exists_xA(x)\rightarrow \forall_x B(x)] \implies  \forall_x [A(x) \rightarrow B(x)]$

Comment: A proof is not just a sequence of formulas that you write down. You have to say *why* each step follows from the previous. You also need to specify a proof system (i.e. axioms and rules of inference) so that you (and we) know what you are allowed to do. If you are not already working in one, then I would recommend looking into a natural deduction system.

Comment: sir pls elaborate.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `propositional-calculus`. I changed tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy, informal, way to prove that $\exists x A(x) \to \forall x B(x)$ implies $\forall x (A(x) \to B(x))$.

It is well-known that $\exists x A(x) \to C$ is equivalent to $\forall x (A(x) \to C)$, provided that the variable $x$ does not occur free in $C$. 
So, from $\exists x A(x) \to \forall x B(x)$ it follows that 
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\forall x (A(x) \to \forall x B(x))
\end{align}
since $x$ is not free in $\forall x B(x)$.
Now, $(1)$ means that, given an $x$ such that $A(x)$ holds, then $B(y)$ holds for every $y$, in particular for $y = x$. 
Therefore, $\forall x (A(x) \to B(x))$ holds.

We proved that $\exists x A(x) \to \forall x B(x)$ implies $\forall x (A(x) \to B(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is:

> Can I say $\forall_x A(x) \rightarrow \forall_x B(x) \implies [ \exists_xA(x)\rightarrow \forall_x B(x)] \implies  \forall_x [A(x) \rightarrow B(x)]$

Running the first conditional in a [tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/) resulted in a countermodel:

[image]

Since $A$ is only true for $0$, $\forall x Ax$ is false, but $\exists xAx$ is true. Since $B$ is not true for any members of the domain, $\forall xBx$ is false. This allows the antecedent to be true and the consequent to be false.

A tree proof succeeded for $[ \exists_xA(x)\rightarrow \forall_x B(x)] \implies  \forall_x [A(x) \rightarrow B(x)]$ which is the goal.

Rather than showing that proof, here is a natural deduction proof in a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/). Since this proof checker uses "A" to code universal quantification, I replaced the symbol "A" with "P" and "B" with "Q":

[image]

The strategy of the proof was to use the law of the excluded middle (LEM) on $\exists xPx \lor \neg \exists xPx$.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: You do not need LEM.  Rather than assuming the existence on line 2, instead just immediately assume $Pa$, and then *introduce* the existence, and from there derive $Qa$, so as to discharge the assumption and deduce $Pa\to Qa$ in the context of arbitrary term $a$.

Comment: $$\small\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~~\exists x~A(x)\to\forall x~B(x)\hspace{10ex}\textsf {Premise}}{\raise{7ex}{[a]}~\begin{array}{|l}{\fitch{~~2.~~A(a)\hspace{16ex}\textsf{Assume}}{~~3.~~\exists x~A(x)\hspace{13ex}\exists\,\mathsf I~2\\~~4.~~\forall x~B(x)\hspace{12.5ex}\to\!\mathsf E~1,3\\~~5.~~B(a)\hspace{16ex}\forall\,\mathsf E~4}\\~~6.~~A(a)\to B(a)\hspace{11.5ex}\to\!\mathsf I~2{-}5}\end{array}\\~~7.~~\forall x~(A(x)\to B(x))\hspace{11ex}\forall\,\mathsf I~6}$$